# SQL something missed.. affected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have used this code in MYSQLI:

```
SELECT da_brands.name AS brand_name,
    COUNT(da_deals.id) AS total_deals,
    0 AS total_downloaded_coupons,
    0 AS total_validated_coupons,
    COUNT(da_logs.id) AS total_likes
FROM da_brands, da_deals LEFT JOIN da_logs
    ON da_logs.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id
    AND da_logs.type = 'deal_like'
WHERE da_brands.fk_club_id = 6
    AND da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id
GROUP BY da_brands.name
ORDER BY da_brands.name ASC
```

RESULTS:

```
brand_name  total_deals    total_downloaded_coupons   total_validated_coupons   otal_likes
Marca2      2              0                          0                         1
Marca1      12             0                          0                         4
```

SHOULD BE:

```
brand_name  total_deals    total_downloaded_coupons   total_validated_coupons   total_likes
Marca2      2              0                          0                         1
Marca1      9              0                          0                         4
```

Any idea?

Comment: So, you're getting the wrong value for Marca1's total_deals, correct?

Comment: yeah! something is adding more to COUNT I think I missed some conditional statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want `COUNT(DISTINCT da_deals.id) AS total_deals,` since you only want to count each deal ID once.

EDIT:  Your `FROM` statement is a list of implicit inner joins (commas) and an explicit outer join.  I missed that.

Your query should probably be written like this, with all explicit joins:

```
SELECT da_brands.name AS brand_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT da_deals.id) AS total_deals,
    0 AS total_downloaded_coupons,
    0 AS total_validated_coupons,
    COUNT(DISTINCT da_logs.id) AS total_likes
FROM da_brands
INNER JOIN da_deals
    ON da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id
LEFT JOIN da_logs
    ON da_logs.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id
    AND da_logs.type = 'deal_like'
WHERE da_brands.fk_club_id = 6
GROUP BY da_brands.name
ORDER BY da_brands.name ASC;
```

To show Brands even when they lack Deals and Likes, try a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT da_brands.name AS brand_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT da_deals.id) AS total_deals,
    0 AS total_downloaded_coupons,
    0 AS total_validated_coupons,
    COUNT(DISTINCT da_logs.id) AS total_likes
FROM da_brands
LEFT JOIN da_deals
    ON da_deals.fk_brand_id = da_brands.id
LEFT JOIN da_logs
    ON da_logs.fk_deal_id = da_deals.id
    AND da_logs.type = 'deal_like'
WHERE da_brands.fk_club_id = 6
GROUP BY da_brands.name
ORDER BY da_brands.name ASC;
```

Comment: OK Thank you, but now what should i do if want to show empty rows for BRANDS, i mean there is a third BRAND not shown with that query.

Comment: @MiguelNavarro-PraiseJesus You'll want to use an `OUTER JOIN` then, like above.  Note that I made both aggregate functions `DISTINCT`.  The one for the Likes is probably unnecessary, but it specifies that you want each Like ID to count exactly once.